# Как при помощи MutationObserver отследить появление на странице элемента div?

Tags: javascript

Делаю расширение добавляющее на страницу кнопку после элемента с классом "name-column", добавляю ее при помощи кода

```js
    var sp = document.createElement("div");
sp.innerHTML = "<button>TEST</button>";
sp.style.paddingRight = "1px";
sp.id = "testid"; //ID должен быть уникален!

document.querySelector(".name-column").appendChild(sp);
```

Но элемента с классом "name-column" изначально нет на странице, он появляется позднее, через разный промежуток времени. Как при помощи MutationObserver узнать когда этот элемент появится, после чего выполнить код добавления кнопки? Ковырял примеры использования MutationObserver, но не понял как им пользоваться, не нашел примера подходящего под мою задачу.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var xxx = document.createElement("div");
  xxx.classList.add('name-column');
  document.body.append(xxx);
})

function createElement() {
  var sp = document.createElement("div");
  sp.innerHTML = "<button>TEST</button>";
  return sp;
}

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  mutationsList.forEach(m => {
    m.addedNodes.forEach(el => {
      if (el.className == 'name-column') el.append(createElement());
    })
  })
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
});
```

```html
<button>add div</button>
```

Comment: Этот код не ищет когда на страницу загрузится элемент с классом "name-column", после чего добавляет кнопку, а просто создает div на странице с классом "name-column" и добавляет кнопку. При чем добавляет не одну, а зацикливает их добавление.

Comment: Как раз таки он следит, когда в body произойдут изменения и попробует добавить в див с классом `name-column` кнопку. На всякий случай исправил ответ и сделал немного по-другому

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at script.js:3 =(

Comment: Надеюсь ты понимаешь, что данная строка просто для примера `const btn = document.querySelector('button');`

Comment: и последующее добавление слушателя к этой кнопке тоже для примера...

Comment: Честно сказать, все равно не понял, как работает. Похоже я безнадежен. Ковырял документацию, смотрел примеры, день убил и до сих пор код не рабочий

Comment: Через таймер работает, но если страница долго грузится, то querySelector вернет "null" и кнопка не появится

Comment: ну заверни это всё в `window.onload`

Comment: Проблема в том, что при полной загрузке страницы на ней нет элемента "name-column", он появляется позже, динамически. При помощи таймера получается отложить проверку на существование "name-column", и если по окончании отсчета таймера элемент уже был создан, то консоль не возвращает ошибку, а если у пользователя на экране еще нет элемента, то консоль выдает ошибку. Реально ли как-то зациклить код, чтобы он перестал выполняться когда элемент появится?

Comment: Я не понимаю тебя. Какие таймеры? какие циклы? Всё что делает код выше - следит за body и если в нём происходят какие-то изменения, он пробегает по всем только что случившимся изменениям и если среди них есть элемент с классом `name-column`, он добавляет в него кнопку. Если нужно, что бы прекратилось наблюдение за `body`, после того как кнопка успешно добавится в элемент с классом `name-column` , можно в `if` добавить строку `observer.disconnect();` . Кнопка `add div` и весь код с ней связанный просто для примера, на его месте может быть всё что угодно, что динамически влияет на `dom`.

Comment: Также, возможно тебе нужно следить не за `body` а за каким-то родительским блоком, в который добавляется элемент с классом `name-column`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать